# Purposely slowing down FPS Spritekit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, frame-rate

Is it possible to purposely slow down the SpriteKit scene's FPS? I was thinking if this is possible to make debugging of my game easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this as well (as an addition to crashoverride777's answer) by slowing down nodes or physics:

To make nodes going into slow-mo (you can do this per node):

```
self.speed = 0.2 //where self is a scene
```

or to do the same with physics:

```
self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.2 //where self is a scene
```

Comment: This is not robust solution. Especially if you have particles in the game and when you have lots of sprites (looping thru sprites could hit performance issues). But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why would you loop through sprites in any case in order to slow them? You change the speed of their parent or change the speed of a scene. @GeneCode

Comment: Also this method gives you possibility to separately slow down a physics world, a complete node tree, or a single node for example...

Comment: I see. Does that mean the particles will be also be slowed down using this method?

Comment: @GeneCode Nope. But neither solution of these two solves that.

Comment: Ok. Do you have idea how to slow everything including particles?

Comment: Not really @GeneCode

Comment: @GeneCode I mean there is a property on SKEmittetNode called particleSpeed, but that will change the behaviour of your particle as well.

Comment: @GeneCode I made a question inspired by your question, so you may want to track it http://stackoverflow.com/q/41805786/3402095

Answer (score 4):

You can change the **FPS** value of your `SKView` when you load the first scene from your `GameViewController`.

Something like:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { 
     skView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30 // 30 FPS 
} else {
     skView.frameInterval = 2 // Deprecated (1 default = 60FPS so 2 would = 30 FPS)
     skView.preferredFrameRate = ... // Deprecated
}
```

As Whirlwind so kindly pointed out in his answer:

"Also, this will not slowdown anything, you just skip frames you are seeing, eg. if you have a node that moves from point A to point B in 5 seconds, and you change preferredFrameRate to 30fps, the node will move from A to B still in 5 seconds, rather than 10. The only change you will see, is that some frames are skipped."

`SKView` API reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview)

Comment: Good answer . Also `frameInterval` is deprecated as explained by the current `SKView` class: `/* Deprecated, please use preferredFramesPerSecond.
       Number of frames to skip between renders, defaults to 1 (render every frame)
       Actual requested rate will be preferredFramesPerSecond / frameInterval.  */
        @available(iOS, introduced: 7.0, deprecated: 10.0)
        open var frameInterval: Int`

Comment: @GeneCode As it can be seen from Alessandro's comment, this property is available only for iOS 10 and above, so you will have to use something like this : `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {...}` if your deployment target is < 10. Also, this will not slowdown anything, you just skip frames you are seeing, eg. node that moves from point A to point B in 5 seconds, and you change preferredFrameRate to 30fps, the node will move from A to B still in 5 seconds, rather than 10. The only change you will see, is that some frames are skipped.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I will update my answer